# iOS app uploads video to youtube using GData and using JSON framework cause Duplicate error

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, video, youtube

I can upload a video to YouTube by using GData framework from my iPhone app. But in my project I also need to have JSON framework. when I integrate them, the app crashes, and the error is:

> duplicate symbol _SBJSONErrorDomain in
>   /Users/jack/Downloads/1Desktop/backup 07:18
>   (F1)/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(SBJSON.o) and
>   /Users/jack/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PostUno-eijnopqdpkkdasbjknrcikkmxpqh/Build/Intermediates/PostUno.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PostUno.build/Objects-normal/i386/SBJsonBase.o
>   for architecture i386
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

When I remove `-ObjC` and `-all_load` linker flags the, error disappear but the app could not upload video to youtube.

Has anyone successfully implemented the GData to upload videos to YouTube and also using JSON framework in the same iphone app? Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: try http://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/youtube-ios-framework/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just removing the JSON framework dependency? It looks like GData already provides an implementation for this. You could have a problem though if the object files do not match the headers you use, so in this case it would be best if the GData version headers were public.

If that does not help you, maybe you can compile GData from source yourself, making sure to use the JSON lib version that your app use?

Having two versions of a library will not work, since the symbol names will collide.